# Run time error in excel vba. last used range rows selects row 65536 instead of actual last used range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to select columns E and K from sheet Input, process in `Working sheet` and paste in the `Output sheet` after the last used row. I have stored the last used row number in x and paste the values in x+1 cell. However excel selects last row of the sheet (x as 65536) and gives run time error 4004. Can someone please help me in assisting the code.

```
Dim x As Long, y As String
    Sheets("Input").Activate
    Range("E:E,K:K").Select
    Range("K1").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Working").Select
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Cells.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("B5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$30").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-1]="""","""",VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Repository!C[-1]:C[1],3,0))"
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B3:B30").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Cells.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("B2:C2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Output").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    x = Worksheets("Output").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    y = "a" & Trim(x + 1)
    ActiveSheet("Output").Range(y).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: UsedRange should be, at best, considered to be advisory: for example, if you insert data in a row then delete that row then UsedRange will include that row. If anything, it's more of a watermark.

Comment: @Bathsheba, "watermark" is a nice image.

Answer (score 1):

Your UsedRange is still thinking that the last row is 65536.  Add this subroutine, then call it right before you set x.

```
Sub CorrectUsedRange()
Dim values
Dim usedRangeAddress As String
Dim r As Range
'Get UsedRange Address prior to deleting Range
usedRangeAddress = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address
'Store values of cells to array.
values = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
'Delete all cells in the sheet
ActiveSheet.Cells.Delete
'Restore values to their initial locations
Range(usedRangeAddress) = values
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Near the bottom of your code replace:

```
Sheets("Output").Select
```

with:

```
Sheets("Output").Select
ActiveSheet.UsedRange
```

this should "re-set" UsedRange

Comment: i am afraid x still takes the last used row as 65536.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the Used Range gets generically large and won't reset on it's own.  When this happens, the only way that I've found to force it to reset itself correctly is to Save the Workbook that the subject Worksheet is in.  This works for me, on Excel 2010 anyway.  Since you're using `.Select` and `Active<obj>` (which I don't recommend), it would simply be this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Find loop to populate an array and then output the array when the macro has completed.  There is no need for a "Working" sheet.  This also uses `Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)` in order to find the last populated row instead of `UsedRange.Rows.Count` which can be unreliable.

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim rngLookup As Range
    Dim arrResults() As Variant
    Dim ResultIndex As Long
    Dim strFirst As String

    With Sheets("Input").Columns("E")
        Set rngFound = .Find("*", .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            strFirst = rngFound.Address
            ReDim arrResults(1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells), 1 To 2)
            Do
                If rngFound.Row > 1 Then
                    ResultIndex = ResultIndex + 1
                    On Error Resume Next    'Just in case the VLookup can't find the value on the 'Repository' sheet
                    arrResults(ResultIndex, 1) = Evaluate("VLOOKUP(""" & rngFound.Value & """,Repository!A:C,3,FALSE)")
                    arrResults(ResultIndex, 2) = .Parent.Cells(rngFound.Row, "K").Value
                    On Error GoTo 0         'Remove the On Error Resume Next condition
                End If
                Set rngFound = .Find("*", rngFound, xlValues, xlWhole)
            Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
        End If
    End With

    If ResultIndex > 0 Then Sheets("Output").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(ResultIndex, UBound(arrResults, 2)).Value = arrResults

    Set rngFound = Nothing
    Erase arrResults

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of used range check how many rows already are filled with this code:

X = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1))

Of course this only works ok if you have no rows that are empty in Column A, as those rows would be ignored!